# Is there a better/shorter syntax for this?

Tags: java, object

I want to make it shorter, making them all true in one line, I don't know if this is possible

```
bckBtn.setEnabled(true);
cBtn.setEnabled(true);
addBtn.setEnabled(true);
btn7.setEnabled(true);
```

***someone gave me this line but I couldn't understand it***

`Streams.of(obj1, obj2).forEach(obj -> obj.setEnable(true));`

sorry if the question was easy, I'm new to java.
thanks again.

Comment: The "hint" code given to you basically performs a function on each element of a Stream of objects. But if you're new to Java I would recommend storing elements in a Collection, like an [ArrayList](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) and then calling `setEnabled` in a loop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here’s the simplest, pre-java 8 and conceptually easiest, code I could come up with.

```
for (Button button : Arrays.asList(bckBtn, cBtn, addBtn, etc)) {
    button.setEnabled(true);
}
```

Comment: I made a little add to it to suite more components

`for (Object obj : Arrays.asList(bckBtn,textField, cBtn, addBtn, etc)) {((Component) obj).setEnabled(true);}`

Comment: @Shift nice! But there’s a cleaner way to do that: `for (Component component : Arrays.asList(bckBtn,textField, cBtn, addBtn, etc)) {component .setEnabled(true);}`

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
Button[] buttons = {bckBtn, cBtn, addBtn, ...};
for (int i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++)
{
    Button temp = buttons[i]; // seconds reference to the buttons[i] object
    temp.setEnabled(true);
}
```